# C# как из текстового файла забрать только цифры

Tags: c#

C# Имею текстовый файл, нужно из него вытащить ТОЛЬКО столбцы цифр и занести отдельно в каждый массив. Определение куда занести то или иное число определяется табуляцией пробелами.
Число создаваемых массивов зависит от кол-во столбцов в текством файле, кол-во цифр в каждом столбце изменяется от нового текстового файла

Шапка файла тестовая часть в отдельную строку, а стобцы цифр в отдельные массивы
На данный момент имею только это:
пример, берет файл в котором три столбца и разделят их на три части, но это не то что мне нужно

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\gg.txt");
string[] one = new string[lines.Length];
string[] two = new string[lines.Length];
string[] tree = new string[lines.Length];


for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
string[] ns = lines[i].Split(' ');
one[i] = ns[0];
two[i] = ns[1];
tree[i] = ns[2];
}

for (int i = 0; i < one.Length; i++)// a.Length;
{
listBox1.Items.Add(one[i].ToString());
listBox2.Items.Add(two[i].ToString());
listBox3.Items.Add(tree[i].ToString());
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните, вам в дальнейшем потребуется работа со столбцами или со строками или и то и другое?

Comment: потребуется только работа со столбцами в массивах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если формат файла имеет стандарт(прочитав данный файл видно, что наименований колонок - 19, ровно как и столбцов данных), то, очевидно, что непосредственно данные, представленные в виде колонок, начинают идти с определенной строки. 
Почему бы Вам для начала не прочитать все названия колонок и не сделать словарь, где ключом будет имя колонки, а значением - массив. Далее с определенной строки(файл стандартен?) считывать данные построчно, последовательно, пока не упретесь в empty(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)). Дошли до emty - предыдущее накопленное строковое значение добавляете в словарь(можно иметь сопоставление порядкового номера и названия колонки), далее читаете до тех пор, пока получите новое не empty значение, читаете до конца и записываете в колонку 2(не забудьте сопоставить имя колонки и ее порядковый номер).
Так, прочитав файл до конца, Вы получите словарь с массивами данных внутри.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но понадобяться только столбцы занесенные в массив, дальше я буду работать только с  массивами, нужен код, а то я не особо понимаю как правильно это сделать